# Source button in google maps from ios application

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, navigation

Hi I'm trying to add the google navigation through my app. I've added the code where i can go to the google with destination and source. But I'm not able to get the source button that is in the documentation of google docs i.e. this [Link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/ios-urlscheme). I'm using the following code to open navigation through my code.

```
let testURL = URL(string: "comgooglemaps-x-callback://")!
    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(testURL) {
        let directionsRequest = "comgooglemaps-x-callback://?daddr=30.712620,76.707575&nav=1&x-success=BTest://?resume=true&x-source=BNB"

        let directionsURL = URL(string: directionsRequest)!
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(directionsURL)
    } else {
        NSLog("Can't use comgooglemapsurl-x-callback:// on this device.")
    }
```

I've also added the URL scheme in info.plist for handling the callback for the application.Below is the image for the info.plist[image]

I need solution for 2 things
1. How to get the source button on the google maps
2. When I open the google maps the navigation should Automatically start as the nav=1 doesn't start the navigation automatically. Any suggestions or links are also appreciated.
TIA

EDIT:
I've already tested the URL scheme is correct and it is opening the application if hit from safari app.

Comment: @did u found any solution? For me, comgooglemapsurl starts the navigation but no back option. Please reply

Comment: @Shyantanu     I've tried a lot, but unfortunately I was not able to get the source button neither the back option on the maps. I Even think it is not possible to back these things.